# git-commit gives no output and nothing is committed

Tags: git

Somehow git seems to be broken on my machine.

1. I ran `git commit` and this triggered our tests, the tests failed.

I fixed something and ran it again.

2. But this time the `git commit` command didn't produce any output. The tests where successful (the test do run, but I don't get any output in the terminal), and I was able to enter my commit message. But after saving it still no output appeared. running `git status` showed all files are still staged and no commit was added.

Every time I run `git commit` again, 2. is repeated.

Does anyone know what is causing this or has encountered this by them self before?

UPDATE:

the entire console log:

```
Jovans-MacBook-Air-3:zmbCORE Jovan$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   jsClient/Admin/App.ts
    modified:   jsClient/Shared/Directives/DataTable/DataTableController.ts
    new file:   jsClient/Shared/Services/PersistentStates.ts

Jovans-MacBook-Air-3:zmbCORE Jovan$ git commit
```

The test run for some time, then the vim commit editor apears, I enter the message and save with `:wq`.

```
Jovans-MacBook-Air-3:zmbCORE Jovan$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   jsClient/Admin/App.ts
    modified:   jsClient/Shared/Directives/DataTable/DataTableController.ts
    new file:   jsClient/Shared/Services/PersistentStates.ts

Jovans-MacBook-Air-3:zmbCORE Jovan$
```

Comment: Please show the console session corresponding to #2 (i.e. exact commands + output for git add, commit, status).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I added the terminal output

Comment: before `git commit` you need to `git add` whatever files you want to commit.  Have you done that?

Comment: @gabe3886 yes if you look at the terminal output is says "Changes to be committed:"

Comment: what happens if you run `git commit -m "your commit message"`

Comment: @gabe3886 same result

Comment: It seems like you have a pre-commit hook. What does it do?

Comment: @torek the pre-commit hook runs our tests and it always worked fine.

Comment: @TitanNano: I'm just wondering if it might affect the commit. In fact all the commit-affecting hooks can be suspects here: pre-commit, prepare-commit-msg, and commit-msg. "It used to work" is a common thread with some kinds of bugs :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem was the malfunctioning `git-hooks` package we are using in our project. And since we run `npm update` before each commit the issue only occurred since the second time I ran the hook.

If you also encounter this issue, I suggest you, to check your git hooks as [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330539/git-commit-gives-no-output-and-nothing-is-committed#comment66009001_39330539).